# not able to get value in view from controller in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this simple code to get data in view but I am not able to get nor I am getting any stack trace

```
     @Controller
        public class ControllerClass {

            @Autowired
            RepoisitiryClass repoisitiryClass;

            @RequestMapping("testData")
            public String getView(Model model) {
                model.addAttribute("getData", repoisitiryClass.setData());
                return "domain";
            }
        }


    public class Domain {
        private String domain;

        public Domain(String domain) {
            this.domain = domain;
        }

        public String getDomain() {
            return domain;
        }
    }

@Repository
    public class RepoisitiryClass {
        private String dataDomain = "";

        public RepoisitiryClass() {
            System.out.println("inside Repo");
            Domain domain = new Domain("this is domain");
            dataDomain = domain.getDomain();
        }

        public String setData() {
            return dataDomain;
        }
    }
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now When ever I try to run url : `http://localhost:8080/Test_path_Variable/testData` it is getting me error 404 page not found.

Is there anyway to solve this error or I am doing somewere wrong?

and project Structure[image]

Comment: Hi! You have `@RequestMapping("testData")`, but what `Test_path_Variable` doing in your url?

Comment: @Optio IDK why, it is running